# Problems printing weight in a NetworkX graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, label, networkx

I'm reading an edgelist using networkX. The edgelist contains entries of the form:

```
1; 2; 3

2; 3; 5

3; 1; 4
```

where 3rd column is the weight. When I plot this, it displays the weight 3 as:

```
{'weight': 3}
```

instead of just 3. Ultimately I want to be able to perform operations using the weight (e.g. calculated highest weight, display only the edges which have a weight:

> 'x', etc.,

Here is the minimal working code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G=nx.read_edgelist('sample_with_weights.edges', data= (('weight',int),))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=4, edge_color='g', edge_labels = 'weight', arrows=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it would help to see the code that is printing the edge - the problem is you are printing a dictionary vs a value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Some observations regarding the existing code:

1. That `read_edgelist` is not going to work well with that edge list file because the 'special' delimiter `;` has not been specified.
2. The edge labels should be specified in the `draw_networkx_edge_labels` function call, rather than the `draw_networkx_edges`; and also
3. The `edge_labels` is *a dictionary keyed by edge two-tuple of text labels (default=None). Only labels for the keys in the dictionary are drawn.* (from [the documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html))

So, the general idea is to use the `edge_labels` to selectively print edge weights. Please see inline comments below:

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt

G=nx.Graph()
#Please note the use of the delimiter parameter below
G=nx.read_edgelist('test.edges', data= (('weight',int),), delimiter=";")
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

#Here we go, essentially, build a dictionary where the key is tuple
#denoting an edge between two nodes and the value of it is the label for
#that edge. While constructing the dictionary, do some simple processing
#as well. In this case, just print the labels that have a weight less
#than or equal to 3. Variations to the way new_labels is constructed
#produce different results.
new_labels = dict(map(lambda x:((x[0],x[1]), str(x[2]['weight'] if x[2]['weight']<=3 else "") ), G.edges(data = True)))

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)

#Please note use of edge_labels below.
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels = new_labels)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=4, edge_color='g', arrows=False)

plt.show()
```

Given a data file `test.edges` that looks like...

```
1;2;3
2;3;3
3;4;3
2;4;4
4;6;5
1;6;5
```

...the above snippet will produce a result similar to:

[image: Conditional printing of edge weights]

Hope this helps.