# Python Networkx how to draw edge weight without the word "weight"

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, graphviz

[image: I only want 0/1 on the edge]

```
from graphviz import *
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(8)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(32)
G.add_node(34)
G.add_edge(8,32,weight=0)
G.add_edge(8,34,weight=1)
G.add_edge(4,8,weight=0)
G.add_edge(4,32,weight=1)


pos=graphviz_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels = edge_labels)
plt.savefig('this.png')
plt.show()
```

So I have just started working with Networkx so I don't know much about the syntax. How can I draw only the weight in this case? I saw that this same code in some other places draw the weight only and not the words "weight".

Thank you.

Comment: nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels={('node1','node2'):'weight-of-1-to-2',
('node2','node4'):'weight-of-2-to-4',font_color='blue') .. try label if that is needed

Comment: Have a look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575634/problems-printing-weight-in-a-networkx-graph The plot in the answer seems to do what you want. Maybe the code helps you to figure out, what you need to adjust.

Comment: @wychmaster the answer in that post has the same code as mine :\

Answer (score 0):

It should be `edge_labels` in `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()`

```
pos=graphviz_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
edgeLabels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = edgeLabels)
plt.savefig('this.png')
plt.show()
```